# Gatsby JS: Dynamically assign Style/Class based on current time?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to dynamically assign a background color to a div using gatsby JS. Everything works well in development but after running a build, the page is static and does not change styles dynamically anymore (same with classes). Please take a quick look at this:

```
let currentTime = new Date().toTimeString()
return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div
        style={{
          background: parseInt(currentTime[7]) % 2 == 0 ? "green" : "yellow",
        }}
      >
        {currentTime}
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

When built, the text renders the current Time correctly, however the style of the div stays static to whatever style gatsby assigned based on the time in the moment of building.

The UseCase for this will be to have a traffic light system to display if a shop is currently open (by comparing opening times to current time)

I am very thankful for any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Import { newGlobalColor } from "styled-components"
const changeDivColor = newGlobalColor`
body { 
    color : ${props => (props.theme ? "yellow" : "green")};
}`
let currentTime = parseInt( new Date().toTimeString()[7])%2;
let return (  
    <React.Fragment>
        <changeDivColor theme={{currentTime}} />
        <div>{currentTime}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please add an explanation to what the code is doing and why it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, it should work with styled-components (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/css-in-js/).

Additionally, you could try to do your magic in gatsby-browser config. (https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/api-files-gatsby-browser/)